# Is there a good alternative approach for my case with positive lookbehind on js?

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

The main problem the positive lookbehind is not supporting in all browsers.
Does exist a good alternative to replacing without a positive lookbehind?

I have:

1. `str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua 5 some parts 735, 2634, 2635, 2640, or 4701 lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'`
2. `regexp = /(?<=(\d+) some (?:part)(?:s)? (?:\d+, (?:or |and )?)*)(\d+)/g,`

I need each digit after **some parts** to wrap in the tag, to have the next look:

```
 <a href="${groupOne}/${groupTwo}">${match}</a>
```

result will be

```
<a href="5/735">735</a>,
<a href="5/2634">2634</a>...
```

etc.

please check the example - https://regex101.com/r/99WCEo/1

Comment: instead of an image, add the link to regex101.

Comment: [lookbehind is now supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=lookbehind) by many browsers (except safari and old IE)

Comment: @Toto sure, the description was updated.

Comment: @Toto about browsers, yeah you are right. And I, unfortunately, need covering safari and ie 11

Comment: That's not a good news ;(. Have you tried to write your own parser?

Comment: @Toto Trying right now, but for now without success :(

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two steps. First use:

```
/(\d+) some parts? (?:\d+, (?:or |and )?)*\d+/g
```

This matches the entire relevant substring `5 some parts 735, 2634, 2635, 2640, or 4701`, and captures these groups:

1. `5`
2. `735, 2634, 2635, 2640, or 4701`

Then search with `/\d+/g` in the second group to extract all the numbers and do the replacement.

Comment: thanks, mate. It will work, but with small adjustments. Thanks